# MYSQL Select message thread id by multiple user ids

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

I'm putting together a threaded messaging service and I am trying to wrap my head a round a particular query.  I am currently trying to create a procedure which will return the thread_id when provided an array of user_ids.

There are only two columns in the table: thread_id & user_id.
I have 4 rows in the table for testing:

```
INSERT INTO thread_users (`thread_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO thread_users (`thread_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (1,70);
INSERT INTO thread_users (`thread_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO thread_users (`thread_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (2,21);
```

This examples user 1 messaging user 70 to start the first thread and then messages user 21 to start thread 2;

Since I already have the ids of both users what I am trying to derive is finding the the thread_id based on the list of users "subscribed" to the thread.

```
SELECT participants.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `thread_id`
    FROM `thread_users` 
    WHERE `thread_users`.`user_id` IN (1, 21)
    GROUP BY `thread_id`
) AS participants
```

There is going to be more data requested through a couple of joins, although I don't want to include it into this question... So, with that said, lets just shorten the query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `thread_id`
FROM `thread_participants` 
WHERE `thread_participants`.`user_id` IN (1, 21)
GROUP BY `thread_id`
```

Of which should return 2.

I recognize that this query should return the proper thread_id wither if there is 2 users associated to a thread or 20.
Any help would greatly appreciated:-) Thank You!

Comment: can you give some output example that you are trying to get?

Comment: (from the original question - "Of which should return 2.") So, querying with the user_id array being (1,21) -> 2  -or- (1, 70) ->1.  it would return one row and the column selected will be thread_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're just trying to get all participants of a thread_id that has user_id 1 and 21

```
SELECT participants.user_id
FROM thread_users as participants
INNER JOIN thread_users as my_people
ON my_people.thread_id = participants.thread_id
WHERE my_people.user_id IN (1,21)
```

if you're trying to get thread_id of your users making sure that they're all participants in the thread. then try this query

```
SELECT participants.thread_id,COUNT(DISTINCT participants.user_id) as participants
FROM thread_users as participants
WHERE participants.user_id IN (1,21)
GROUP BY participants.thread_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT participants.user_id)=2
```

the last line just makes sure that your COUNT of DISTINCT user_id is equal to 2 which means your 2 user_id of 1 and 21...
If you wanted to find thread of users (1,21,70) you'd replace the (1,21) with (1,21,70) and change that bottom line to `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT participants.user_id)=3` then it would return the thread that has those 3 people as participants.

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you, Tin Tran!

Comment: was it the 2nd query that you were after?

Comment: sure was! I plugged it into the subquery as mentioned before and it got me to the right place. Thank you! This will make for a very productive morning tomorrow.